# CRM 2011 Merging records using dialog

Tags: dialog, merge, duplicates, dynamics-crm, crm

Morning guys. I will try to be as short as possible. 
We are using CRM 2011 on premises. Currently the way data flow works is that we have two systems (system X and System Y). System X have all customer information regarding purchase and System Y have all the information regarding customer's subscription choice. (news letter etc)

We bring these two database together and merge it in to one and then using thirdparty service, push it in to the CRM. (we process these data that's de-dups rows, checks for data quality etc)

PROBLEM start when the third type of data gets entered in by customer service. This guys uses Outlook to push data in to CRM (this are the only data that goes directly in to CRM)
This last method creates lots of duplicates and makes it imposible to use this data for better customer service and reporting. 
Few important info: over 99% of data (in form of cases) entered in to CRM by customer service are of customers who already exist in CRM (These are the data that came from System X and System Y). The existing data have all the details (email, postal address etc..) but duplicate data that is entered by Customer service only have basic info like Firstname, Lastname and Email address.

what is the best solution to 1. merge these datas? and 2. Avoid duplicates when entered by customer services? I tried using dialog but it's asking end user (in customer service) to manually pick details they want to keep from each row. Some time these rows are more then 2-3. 
I am sorry for making it so long but this issue seems to not going away. I am not looking for full on solution from you guys but any tips, link or if you have tried some thing like this before.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at duplicate detection rules?

E.g. [CRM Duplicate Detection Part 1: Configure Settings and Create Rules](http://blog.rbaconsulting.com/blog/bid/190150/CRM-Duplicate-Detection-Part-1-Configure-Settings-and-Create-Rules)

Comment: So what will happen if Duplicate Detection finds a duplicate value? At the moment, evry entry from customer service is creating duplicate record. 1. Will it ask end user to merge records 2. will it delete one of them (if so which one) and 3. can I define how to merge records automatically. Thanks for your help buddy :)

Comment: It will inform the user they are about to create a duplicate and ask them what they want to do. You can also have jobs running in the background which find existing duplicates. Its eaiser for you to try it out than for me to explain it.

Comment: Agree, it's always easy to try it. Thanks James. I will look in to it. One of the reason we are getting these duplicates is because end users who are entering these data are, let me honest, don't care. Giving them choice on which data to keep might be a terrible idea. What I am struggling to understand is that when they raise case, WHY it's creating duplicates. In other words, trying to find out prevention then fix. Hey ho, I will have to just flag these data for now as potential duplicates so they don't get included in marketing list etc...Thanks for your help :)